# For a class derived from dict, can I deepcopy only the aspect that is derived from dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x, deep-copy

I have an object of a class derived from `dict` with several additions of functionality. Nevertheless, after a certain point it gets used by parts of the program only as a `dict`, so the additional functionality plays no role to those parts of the program.

So in order to make sure that no callee would be able to manipulate the actual `dict` aspect of my class instance, I was thinking of "extracting" its dict aspect using `copy.deepcopy`.

1. is that at all possible?
2. how do I pull it off?

In C++ I'd be able to do a `dynamic_cast<>` to get a type that I want.

Comment: Hell, just do `dict(instance_of_subclass)`. `dict` will think it one of its own, as long as you haven't customized iteration to the point that `dict` won't accept it.

Comment: @Lord_DeathMatch: I haven't customized that aspect. Will this still require a subsequent `deepcopy`?

Comment: not sure, depends on if you don't want the objects inside the new dict to affect the originals inside the `dict`-like object. Depends on your use case

Comment: @Lord_DeathMatch: okay, then that's a yes. I don't want them to be affected. Please write it up as an answer. I am currently verifying that it works as expected. Will then be able to upvote and accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `dict` object will accept any iterable that yields `(key,value)` tuples (or any dict like object, see [1](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict)). Presuming that iteration has not been modified on the custom object, you should be able to do something like so;

```
import copy
dict_version = copy.deepcopy(dict(dict_like_object))
```